# how to import javax.script? Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
```

I try to import these two pacakges into spring boot java program. But I got the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAA9i.png):

```
package javax.script does not exist.
```

I know I need to write down the dependency into `pom.xml` such as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNYUw.png)
But I don't know exactly what do I need to write.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very newbie question when I was just engaged into Java development, basically the dependences are controller by Maven, and we can go to Maven repository to see what packages and versions we can use into our project.
See this one:
https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).